# Compare versions without using version CPAN module

Tags: perl

Assume I have 2 version variables:

```
$one = "1.2.3"
$two = "1.2.4"
```

How do I compare these two version variables on whether the versions match OR one > two OR one < two?

Please note that I have a read-only system where I cannot add any Perl modules. Hence I cannot add `version` Perl module.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Why not use the *Core* version module instead of getting the version module from *CPAN*?

Comment: [`version`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version/Internals.pod) **is** simple Perl.

Comment: I have a read only system where i cannot add any modules

Comment: Again, the version modules come with Perl, so it doesn't need to be added. (Also, you don't need any special permissions to install modules. If you can add a script, you can install a module.)

Comment: What error are you seeing by adding `use version` to the top of your script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the strings you posted, the standard string comparison operators (`cmp`, `lt`, etc) will work as long as every component is less than 10.

For the strings you posted, the standard string comparison operators (`cmp`, `lt`, etc) will work as long as every component is less than 2<sup>32</sup> if you transform them using `pack('N*', split(/\./, $v))` first.

But that won't work for all versions commonly seen in the Perl world. If that's the kind of versions with which you must deal, use the version module. (This doesn't require installing anything from CPAN, so it meets your demands.)

```
my $v1 = version->parse($one);
my $v2 = version->parse($two);
```

The created objects override the numerical and string comparison operators so that they may be used to compare the objects.

Comment: Standard comparison operators will not work for these versions, consider: `1.2.9` vs `1.2.10`.

Comment: @Grinnz, My answer was technically correct since I only promised it would work for the strings `1.2.3` and `1.2.4`. :) But that wasn't my intention or the implication. I have adjusted my answer. I was very tired at the time, which is very evident because 1) that should have been obvious to me, and 2) I knew something was wrong, so I actually tested the solution I posted, including something in the tens vs something not in the tens. Either I misread the output, or I forgot the quotes (because `perl -E'say 1.2.9 cmp 1.2.10'` works because they're vstrings). Pretty sure it was the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the following solution will fit your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sign;

my $prev = <DATA>;

chomp $prev;

while( my $new = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $new;

    my $str_new  = $new;
    my $str_prev = $prev;

    $str_prev =~ s/\.//g;
    $str_new  =~ s/\.//g;

    my $d_length = length($str_prev) - length($str_new);

    $str_new  .= '0' x  $d_length if $d_length > 0;
    $str_prev .= '0' x -$d_length if $d_length < 0;

    $sign = "=" if $str_new == $str_prev;
    $sign = ">" if $str_new > $str_prev;
    $sign = "<" if $str_new < $str_prev;

    printf "%-5s %s %-5s\n", $new, $sign, $prev;

    $prev = $new;
}


__DATA__
1.2.3
1.2.4
1.2
1.3.5
1.3.5
1.3.0
```

The code is open to productive critique.

If you need to know which version is *bigger*, *smaller* or *equal* then **cmp** on two numbers would be sufficient.